# Magento 2.4: How to add an external Javascript to a CMS Page or Static Block

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, external-script

I got an external JavaScript which is working fine outside of Magento. But if I want to insert that script into a CMS page of Magento 2.4.x there is nothing displayed. Tried a lot of different things

The Script is like the follow:

```
(function(w,d,o,u,a,f,e,n){w[a]=w[a]||{};
      for(i=0;i<f.length;i++){w[a][f[i]]=w[a][f[i]]||function(i){ return function(){
      (w[a][f[i]].q=w[a][f[i]].q||[]).push(arguments)}}(i)}e=d.createElement(o),
      n=d.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
    })(window,document,'script',
    'https://45005902784af655b3de3-5ad26d8a78e52ca19e00dd2d340c77bb.ssh.cf3.rackcdn.com/dot/js/dot-embed/dot-embed-3.0.js',
    'dotEmbed',
    ['load']);
    (function(app){
      app.load(document.getElementById('dot-embed-617817dafbf318388c46ea4b'), {
        dotId: 249,
        pageId: '6178172dafbf318388c46ea4b',
        height: '100vh',
        width: '100%'
      });
    })(window.dotEmbed);

<div id='dot-embed-6178172dafbf318388c46ea4b'></div>
```

***thanks***